# Creating matrix based on knowing the dimensions in a pattern

Tags: r

I tried to solve a problem programmatically, but was unsuccessful.  Here are some of the the examples to generate

```
 cbind(1:12,13:2,3:14,15:4,5:16,17:6,7:18,19:8,9:20,21:10)

 cbind(1:11,12:2,3:13,14:4,5:15,16:6,7:17,18:8,9:19)
```

Looking for a general solution for this problem.  If the number of columns and rows are given, the program should output the matrix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it fairly easily using [apply](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html). Just generate the matrix columns counting `y` steps up from the column number, and reverse the even columns;

```
> x=5; y=7

> apply(t(1:x), 2, function(x) if(x%%2) x-1+1:y else x-1+y:1)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    8    3   10    5
[2,]    2    7    4    9    6
[3,]    3    6    5    8    7
[4,]    4    5    6    7    8
[5,]    5    4    7    6    9
[6,]    6    3    8    5   10
[7,]    7    2    9    4   11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m = embed(1:19, 9)
m[, seq(2, ncol(m), by=2)] = m[nrow(m):1, seq(2, ncol(m), by=2)]
m[,ncol(m):1]
```

produces

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    1   12    3   14    5   16    7   18    9
 [2,]    2   11    4   13    6   15    8   17   10
 [3,]    3   10    5   12    7   14    9   16   11
 [4,]    4    9    6   11    8   13   10   15   12
 [5,]    5    8    7   10    9   12   11   14   13
 [6,]    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14
 [7,]    7    6    9    8   11   10   13   12   15
 [8,]    8    5   10    7   12    9   14   11   16
 [9,]    9    4   11    6   13    8   15   10   17
[10,]   10    3   12    5   14    7   16    9   18
[11,]   11    2   13    4   15    6   17    8   19
```